# Adding validation in ms access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to add validation in one my field. I would like to add a dot at the end of access validation if the users enters 1 characters. The max length is 2.

e.g if User enters "A" then it should show as "A."

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox:

```
If Len(Nz(Me!YourTextbox.Value)) = 1 Then
    Me!YourTextbox.Value = Me!YourTextbox.Value & "."
End If
```